# Space consumed by a particular column's data and impact on deleting that column

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I am using Oracle 12c database in my project and I have a column "Name" of type `"VARCHAR2(128 CHAR) NOT NULL "`. I have approximately 25328687 rows in my table.

Now I don't need the "Name" column so I want to delete it. When I calculated the total size of the data in this column(using lengthb and vsize) for all the rows it was approximately 1.07 GB.

Since the max size of the data in this column is specified, isn't all the rows will be allocated 128 bytes for this column (ignoring unicode for simplicity) and the total space consumed by this column should be 128 * number of rows = 3242071936 bytes or 3.24 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Varchar2 allocate memory dynamically (definition says variable length string data type)
Char datatype is fixed length string data type.

```
create table x (a char(5), b varchar2(5));
insert into x value ('RAM', 'RAM');
insert into x value ('RAMA', 'RAMA');
insert into x value ('RAMAN', 'RAMAN');

SELECT * FROM X WHERE length(a) = 3; -> this will return 0 record
SELECT * FROM X WHERE length(b) = 3; -> this will return 1 record (RAM)

SELECT length(a) len_a, length(b) len_b from x ; 
o/p will be like below
len_a | len_b
-------------
5     | 3
5     | 4
5     | 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle do dynamic allocation for varchar2 .

So a string of 4 char will take 5 bytes one for the length and 4 bytes for 4 char , if one-byte character set .

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say, the storage that a `VARCHAR2` column uses is **VAR**ying. To get an estimate of the actual amount, you can use

1) The data dictionary

```
SELECT column_name, avg_col_len, last_analyzed
  FROM ALL_TAB_COL_STATISTICS
 WHERE owner        = 'MY_SCHEMA'
   AND table_name   = 'MY_TABLE'
   AND column_name  = 'MY_COLUMN';
```

The result `avg_col_len` is the average column length. Mulitply it by your number of rows 25328687 and you get an estimate of roughly how many bytes this column uses. (If `last_analyzed` is NULL or very old compared to the last big data change, you'll have to refresh the optimizer stats with `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('MY_SCHEMA','MY_TABLE')` first.

2) Count yourself in sample

```
SELECT sum(s), count(*), avg(s), stddev(s)
  FROM (
        SELECT vsize(my_column) as s 
          FROM my_schema.my_table SAMPLE (0.1)
       );
```

This calculates the storage size of a 0.1 percent sample of your table.

3) To know for sure, I'd do a test of with a subset of the data

```
CREATE TABLE my_test TABLESPACE my_scratch_tablespace NOLOGGING AS 
  SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table SAMPLE (0.1);

-- get the size of the test table in megabytes
SELECT round(bytes/1024/1024) as mb 
  FROM dba_segments WHERE owner='MY_SCHEMA' AND segment_name='MY_TABLE';

-- now drop the column
ALTER TABLE my_test DROP (my_column);

-- and measure again
SELECT round(bytes/1024/1024) as mb 
  FROM dba_segments WHERE owner='MY_SCHEMA' AND segment_name='MY_TABLE';

-- check how much space will be freed up
ALTER TABLE my_test MOVE;

SELECT round(bytes/1024/1024) as mb 
  FROM dba_segments WHERE owner='MY_SCHEMA' AND segment_name='MY_TABLE';
```

You could improve the test by using the same `PCTFREE` and `COMPRESSION` levels on your test table.